# Does a homomorphism of rings always send ideals into ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A basic algebra question: does a homomorphism of rings always send ideals into ideals?

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is no. Let's see why.

---

Let $\varphi : R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Suppose $I$ is an ideal of $R$. Let us check the requirements that $\varphi(I)$ is an ideal of $S$.

---

Suppose $a,b \in \varphi(I)$. Then there exist $a',b' \in I$ such that $\varphi(a') = a$ and $\varphi(b') = b$. Then: $$ a + b = \varphi(a') + \varphi(b') = \varphi(a' + b') \in \varphi(I)$$

Therefore $\varphi(I)$ is closed under addition.

---

Now to check closure under scalar multiplication:

Suppose $s \in S$. Here is where we run into a problem. If $s$ were in the image of $\varphi$, there wouldn't be an issue because $$sa = \varphi(s')\varphi(a') = \varphi(s'a')$$ where $s' \in R$ is such that $\varphi(s') = s$.

So if $S \neq im(\varphi)$, then $\varphi(I)$ may not be an ideal of $S$.

---

Example: Let $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the inclusion map and $I = \langle 2 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. Then $\varphi(I)$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

For instance: $2 \in \varphi(I), x \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$; but $x \cdot 2 = 2x \notin \varphi(I)$.